# Jupyter Notebook switches to old interface in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

When I open a new Jupyter notebook using the command palette in VS code, it opens in the new interface (see https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/08/05/notebooks).

[image]

However, when I close the file and then reopen it, the file opens in the old interface, along with a depreciation warning.

[image]

How can I always use the new interface (without using VS Code Insiders)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vscode probably still has the old editor as default for the noteboook extension you are trying to open. You can change the default editor in the IDE itself, with a workspace containing any file with such an extension.
Right-click on one of the files with the extension you want to set to the new VSCode editor and select "Open With...".

[image: Image showing the right click options on any jupyter file]

Select "Configure default editor for '*.ipynb'..."
[image: Dialog with the editors available for such file and at last the option to set the default editor]

Finally, select "Jupyter Notebook, Built-in"
[image: Dialog with the editors available for such file]

Now VSCode should always open notebooks with that extension in its new UI, unless you specify another editor with the Open With option.